# How to get a single value in findbyPk() method in yii?

Tags: yii

In my controller

```
$agent = University::model()->findByPK($university_id);
```

I hope it will return value of a row of value.
I want a single attribute(field3) value say `university_name`, (with out using findByPK), how to get it

```
SELECT  field3 FROM table [WHERE Clause]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
$usercriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$usercriteria->select = "university_name";
$usercriteria->condition = "university_id=$university_id";
$university = University::model()->findAll($usercriteria);

echo $university->university_name;
```

Or simply do like u did first

```
$agent = University::model()->findByPK($university_id);
echo $agent-> university_name;
```

Comment: I'm getting: Trying to get property of non-object. What does that mean??

Comment: if you are using first one, replace `findAll` with `find`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$agent = University::model()->findByPK($university_id);
echo $agent->university_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this:

```
$agent = University::model()->findByPK($university_id)->university_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$university_name = University::model()->findByPK($university_id, array('select'=>'univeersity_name'))->university_name;
#Query: SElECT university_name FROM table_name where id=x;
```

Instead of

```
$university_name = University::model()->findByPK($university_id)->university_name;
#Query: SElECT * FROM table_name where id=x;
```

Second query returns all the fields. So better to avoid those fields are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

in case if you need to view on the yii _views, i have implemented this on my project
i put this  inside my '_view.php' at /protected/views/myTable/

```
$agent = University::model()->findByPK($data->id_university/*this is the PK field name*/);
echo $agent->university_name /*university field name*/;
```

sorry again for my bad english :o

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
$agent = University::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('field3'),"WHERE `id` = :id", array(':id' => $university_id));
```

First argument of findByAttributes is an array of attributes you wish it to return. If left empty it returns all (*).